# OpsHub - User Mapping - First Name Last Name vs (Azure) Last Name, First Name

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are trying to migrate our projects from TFS to VSO using the #OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility.  However, when it brings up the user mapping it show the Team Foundation Users as Last Name, First Name and the Visual Studio Online users as First Name then Last Name.  The don't automatically map.  We hve over 240 user to map, to have to do this manually for each migration would be unreasonable.  Is there something we can do so that the mapping will occur for these users automatically?  Or that the system can map via email address?

One note, I was able to take my own user profile and edit the display name to be last name comma first and it was able to automatically map in the utility.  However, having to do this for 240 users again would be tedious.

Also, when we are setting up users and the system searches for them, it pulls the users from our Azure account.

Comment: No, we're afraid there is not automated workaround for this.

Comment: We will have our users update their display name to match in both systems.   However, this will only catch about 1/4 of the users many are gone or no longer used.  These will have to be mapped manually.  My follow up question is...
If we go through the process in the application of mapping the users to a rollup, will the application remember the mapping during one migration so when we migrate another project we will not have to do the mapping again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently OpsHub Migration Utility supports auto-mapping for same display name of users. If you have same email id in both end points then you can use more flexible tool OpsHub Integration Manager for customized migration. For more details on OIM contact sales@opshub.com

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this. You need to update the users' display name or map them manually in Opshub.